# How to break from forEach loop when exception occur

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a forEach loop inside a for loop. Something like this.

```
for (Iterator iterator = notLoadedFiles.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            SwapReport swapReport = (SwapReport) iterator.next();
            Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(swapReport.getFilePath()));
            CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT);
            List<CSVRecord> initList = csvParser.getRecords();
            
            CSVRecord csvRecord = initList.stream().filter(record -> record.get(0).endsWith("@xxx.com")).findAny().orElse(null);
            if (csvRecord != null) {
                // partition the list
                List<List<CSVRecord>> output = ListUtils.partition(initList, chunkSize);

                // Set data by slice
                output.stream().forEach(slice -> {
                    String inParams = slice.stream().filter(record -> !record.get(0).endsWith("@xxx.com")).map(record -> "'" + record.get(0) + "'").collect(Collectors.joining(",")).toString();
                    try {
                          // Retrieve data for one slice
                          setAccountData(inParams);
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException e) {  
                        // How to break ?
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

The forEach loop will execute the setAccount method. The  try catch block inside the forEach loop is because setAccount throwing SQLException.

What I want to do is to stop(break) from the forEach loop in case there is an exception.

If there is an exception the inner loop will stop and for loop (outer loop) will proceed to the next element in the iterator.

How can I do that ?

Thank you

Comment: Thanks, I will change back to native for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, function `.ForEach()` **did not** provided a good way to break the loop. Although adding a `return` statement inside this loop could let the `.ForEach()` to **continue next loop**, but I'm sure that's not what you are asking.

**Solution**

Therefore, you can try to use a feature call `.takeWhile()` introduced in **Java 9**. For example, the code will be:

```java
boolean varNameYouPrefer = true;
output.stream().takeWhile(slice -> varNameYouPrefer).forEach(slice -> {
    String inParams = slice.stream().filter(record -> !record.get(0).endsWith("@xxx.com")).map(record -> "'" + record.get(0) + "'").collect(Collectors.joining(",")).toString();
    try {
            // Retrieve data for one slice
            setAccountData(inParams);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {  
        // To break, set varNameYouPrefer to false.
        varNameYouPrefer = false;
    }
});
```

**References**

- [Java Stream Document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)
- [Example of using takeWhile](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-takewhile-method-in-java-with-examples/)